# Multiple data from different sources on time series forecasting

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, lstm

I have an interesting question about time series forecasting. If someone has temporal data from multiple sensors, each dataset would have data, e.g., from 2010 to 2015, so if one were to train a forecasting model using all the data from those different sensors, how should the data be organized? because if one just stacked up the data set, it would generate, e.g., sensorDataset1 (2010–2015), sensorDataset2 (2010–2015), and the cycle would start over with sensors 3, 4, and n. Is this a problem with time series data or not?
If yes, what is the proper way to handle this?

I tried using all the data stacked up and training the model anyway, and actually it has a good error, but I wonder if that approach is actually valid.

Answer (score 1):

Try sampling your individual sensor data sets to the same period.

For example, if sensor 1 has a data entry every 5 minutes and sensor 2 has an entry every 10 minutes. Try to sample your data to a common period across all sensors. Each data point you show to your model will have better quality data that should influence the performance of your model.

The aspect that will influence your error depends on what you're trying to forecast and the relationships that exist in your data that showcase the relationship between variables.

Comment: Yes, but in this specific case all sensors have entries for the same amount of time, which is for each hour. The multiple sensors started on the same date and gathered data at the same time, once an hour. What would be the better solution to this case? And thank you for answering!

Comment: Maybe i should also mention that those sensors collect the same type of data but each of them are in different environments.

Comment: If all your data has the same periodicity then analyse the relationships that exist between variables before selecting features for your model. Run cross-evaluation on multiple modelling techniques to select the best for your specific problem. There's no best option for the technique to use but check out Facebook's Prophet model, it performs decently well for time series forecasting